# Asymptotic analysis, approximation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, asymptotics

While solving the quantum harmonic oscillator differential equation in 3 dimensions:

$$
E \psi = -\frac{\hbar^2} {2\mu}\nabla^2 \psi + \frac{1}{2}\mu\omega^2r^2 \psi
$$
for the radial equation, we get:

$$
\frac{d^2 R}{d \rho^2} +\frac{2}{\rho}\frac{dR}{d \rho}+\left (\frac{2E}{\hbar \omega} - \rho^2 - \frac{l(l+1)}{\rho^2}\right)R =0
$$
My doubt is: when we perform asymptotic  analysis on the equation to guess the form of the solution we have:
$$
\frac{d^2 R}{d \rho^2}- \rho^2R= 0
$$
for large values of $\rho$. And in all of my text books and notes, approximates the solution to a gaussian:
$$
R(\rho) \approx e^{-\rho^2/2}
$$
But, furthermore, they use $-\rho^2/2$ in the exponent, instead of just $-\rho^2$. Could someone explain and prove, why this approximation is valid for large values of $\rho$?

Comment: Notice that there is an exact solution of the differential equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factor of one-half is needed to make the equation come out right. The derivatives are

$
\frac{dR}{d\rho}=-\rho\,e^{-\rho^2/2}
$

and

$
\frac{d^2R}{d\rho^2}=-e^{-\rho^2/2}+\rho^2\,e^{-\rho^2/2}
$

But in the limit $\rho\gg1$, the second term on the right-hand side is much larger than the first. Hence

$
\frac{d^2R}{d\rho^2}\sim\rho^2\,e^{-\rho^2/2}
$

and

$
\frac{d^2R}{d\rho^2}-\rho^2R\sim\rho^2\,e^{-\rho^2/2}-\rho^2\,e^{-\rho^2/2} = 0
$

as desired. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks!!! This was, what I was searching for

Comment: Glad I could help!